# create an array based on size from derived class

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, matrix, abstract-class

So i have an abstract class named `Matrice` containing a matrix of complex numbers

```
class Matrice {
    Complex** v;      //matrix
public:
    Matrice() {
        v = new Complex * [//lin];    //use size here, without declaring it here
        for (int i = 0; i < //lin; i++) {
            v[i] = new Complex[//col];
            for (int j = 0; j < //col; j++)
                cin >> v[i][j];
        }
    }
    virtual void afisare(int lin, int col) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                cout << v[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

and it's derived class

```
class Matrice_oarecare :Matrice {
    int lin, col;    //the size i want to use
public:
    Matrice_oarecare();
    ~Matrice_oarecare() {

    }
    void afisare() { Matrice::afisare(lin, col); }
};
```

the question is how do i dynamically allocate my matrix using the size specified in my derived class `Matrice_oarecare`, sorry for the dumb question but i'm new to this inheritance thing

Comment: Any reason you can't pass `lin` and `col` as arguments to `Matrix`'s constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Matrice_oarecare inherits from Matrice, it has visibility on all *protected* attributes of Matrice class.

If you want to have access to `Complex**v` from the derived class then
`Complex**v` should protected in the base class.

and to allocate in Matrice_oarecare:

```
v = new Complex*[lin];
for(int i = 0; i < lin; ++i)
   v[i] = new Complex[col];
```

**Alternative**

You can have a function called `allocate`in the base class that allocates the `Complex**` array like so :

```
class Matrice{
    void allocate(int rows, int cols){
           v = new Complex*[rows];
           for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
                v[i] = new Complex[cols];
    }
}
```

and call it from the constructor of the derived class. So you will have

```
class Matrice_oarecare :Matrice {
    int lin, col;   
public:
    Matrice_oarecare(int rows, int cols):lin(rows),col(cols){
          Matrice::allocate(lin, col);
    }
    ~Matrice_oarecare() {

    }
    void afisare() { Matrice::afisare(lin, col); }
};
```

also you can have `lin`and `col` taken as parameters to the contructor of `Matrice`

Comment: it has to be private

Answer (score 0):

Why not just overload the constructor?
You can pass the parameters of the derived constructor to the base_class constructor and than use those parameters as you see fit.

```
class Matrice {
    Complex** v;      //matrix
public:
    Matrice(int lin, int cols) {
        v = new Complex * [lin];    //use size here, without declaring it here
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
            v[i] = new Complex[cols];
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                cin >> v[i][j];
        }
    }
    virtual void afisare(int lin, int col) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                cout << v[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};


class Matrice_oarecare :Matrice {
    int lin, col;    //the size i want to use
public:
   Matrice_oarecare():
      Matrice(lin, col) {};

   ~Matrice_oarecare() {}

   void afisare() { Matrice::afisare(lin, col); }
};
```